# Rspec blows up because of a failing check in an untested class initializer. Is this because of Rails autoloading classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a service object in my Rails application which raises a `ConfigurationError` if it hasn't been configured properly:

```
module Import
  class ImportedObject
    ...

    def initialize(*args)
      raise ConfigurationError unless Import.configured?
      super
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

In development everything runs fine. Running rspec however immediately fails with `.../app/services/import/imported_object.rb:16:in 'initialize': Import should be configured with 'Import.configure_for company, origin' (Import::ConfigurationError)`, even though no spec touches any Import class (yet ;)).

Is this caused by Rails' autoloading (and apparently initializing?) of all classes in all environments except development?

How can I properly load this class and still be able to raise the exception when the configuration is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, it seems this issue wasn't caused by Rails or rspec.

I'm using [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) to define attributes in `ImportObject` and it's subclasses.

I also defined a `composed_of` method in a DSL module that extends the ImportObject, it's used in a few subclasses:

```
# DSL for composition
def composed_of(klass, attribute_name, options = {})
  ...      
  # Set an attribute that  contains the proxied class and delegate methods defined in constant
  attribute attribute_name, klass, default: klass.new 
  ...
end
```

`klass.new` is what caused the exception, putting it in a proc solves this issue. I guess `composed_of` is evaluated when rspec initializes.

Answer (score 0):

Before any test is run, rspec prepares the environment - it means it execute application.rb, environment.rb and all initializers. Do you initialize your Imports there?

Comment: No, I haven't explicitly initialized `ImportObject` or any other Import related module or class in one of the files you mentioned. `ImportObject` is never initialized directly, because it serves as a superclass for the other specific imported objecttypes, for example `ImportedInvoice`, `ImportedDebtor` etc. Cheers for the pointer!